# i'm in trouble with datareader

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

having a problem with this part of my code, with datareader.

```
foreach (Giorno iDet in iNom.Gg.Where(x => x.minRegular != 0 | x.minOver != 0 | x.minLate != 0))
{
    bool Importato = false;
    com = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, Lavorato, Straordinario, Assenza, Permesso, Malattia, Infortunio, Ferie, Maternita, Ritardo, Festivita " +
                         "FROM presenze_giorno WHERE data = @data AND reparto = @rep AND nomcod = @nom", TranOP.Connection, TranOP);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("data", iDet.Gg);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("rep", iNom.Reparto);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("nom", iNom.Codice);                                
    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
        Importato = true;                                                      
    if (!Importato)
    {
        //Inserisco il giorno
        com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO presenze_giorno (data, reparto, nomcod, nomdesc, errmarcatura, ingresso, uscita, " +
                             "Lavorato, Ritardo, Straordinario, Assenza) VALUES " +
                             "(@data, @reparto, @nomcod, @nomdesc, @errmarcatura, @ingresso, @uscita, @Lavorato, @Ritardo, " +
                             "@Straordinario, @Assenza); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", TranOP.Connection, TranOP);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("data", iDet.Gg);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("reparto", iNom.Reparto);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("nomcod", iNom.Codice);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("nomdesc", iNom.Descrizione);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("errmarcatura", iNom.MarcaturaSbagliata);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("ingresso", iDet.Gg.Add(iDet.InT));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("uscita", iDet.Gg.Add(iDet.OutT));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Lavorato", iDet.minRegular);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ritardo", iDet.minLate);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Straordinario", iDet.minOver);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Assenza", iDet.minAssente);
        int wid = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        //Inserisco le marcature
        Lettura search = Lett.Find(f => f.Data == iDet.Gg & f.Reparto == iNom.Reparto & f.Codice == iNom.Codice);
        if (search != null)
            foreach (IngrUsc item in search.IU)
            {
                com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO presenze_marcature (idtesta, ingresso, uscita) VALUES (@idtesta, @ingresso, @uscita)", TranOP.Connection, TranOP);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("idtesta", wid);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("ingresso", iDet.Gg.Add(item.InT));
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("uscita", iDet.Gg.Add(item.OutT));
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
    }                             
    //controllo se tutti gli altri campi sono a 0, se si faccio Update                                                                
    else if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["Lavorato"]) == 0 & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Straordinario"]) == 0 & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Assenza"]) == 0 & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Permesso"]) == 0 
             & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Malattia"]) == 0 & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Infortunio"]) == 0 & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ferie"]) == 0 & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Maternita"]) == 0 
             & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ritardo"]) == 0 & Convert.ToInt32(dr["Festivita"]) == 0)
    {
        com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Presenze_Giorno " +
                             "SET Lavorato = @lav, Straordinario = @stra, Assenza = @ass, Permesso = @perm, Malattia = @mala, Infortunio = @inf,  " +
                             "Ferie = @ferie, Maternita = @mat, Ritardo = @rit, Festivita = @fest" +
                             "WHERE data = @data AND reparto = @rep AND nomcod = @nom", TranOP.Connection, TranOP);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("data", iDet.Gg);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("rep", iNom.Reparto);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("nom", iNom.Codice);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("lav", iDet.minRegular);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("stra", iDet.minOver);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("ass", iDet.minAssente);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("perm", iDet.minPermesso);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("mala", iDet.minMalattia);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("inf", iDet.minInfortunio);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("ferie", iDet.minFerie);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("mat", iDet.minMaternita);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("rit", iDet.minLate);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("fest", iDet.minFestivita);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    dr.Close();
```

When i do the else if and try to convert to int 32 dr["Lavorato"] ecc,ecc gives my an error.

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'A Command è già associato un
>   DataReader aperto, che deve essere chiuso."

Comment: Command and DataReader are disposable so should be in `using` statements. Comment rather than an answer as I don't know whether this will solve your issue, but you should do it anyway, especially as this is within a foreach loop.

Comment: Have you activated `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` in web config's connection string? Seems your code trying to execute a query while still iterating over the results from another query (marked by error `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataReader`, unlike other .NET database classes, is not disconnected from database. That means that it needs open connection and dedicated command. MSDN states:

> You can use the ADO.NET DataReader to retrieve a read-only,
>   forward-only stream of data from a database. Results are returned as
>   the query executes, and are stored in the network buffer on the client
>   until you request them using the Read method of the DataReader.

You can solve your problem using two ways:

- have `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` set in your command's connection string
- have another command that works with data. So, instead reusing `com` instance, make new one, like this: `SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO presenze_giorno ...`

also, another few things:

don't forget to close `DataReader` to free resources and close connection.  Best approach is to use it in `using block`, like this:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
{
    //rest of your code
}
```

and, looks like you're not calling `Read` method of your dataReader, so DataReader is not advancing to first row and stays "before" first row. You can to it like this:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
    Importato = true;    
dr.Read();
```

Comment: @frnbrt22 marking my answer as a solution is a way to say thanks :)